# strange issue with js in updatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a link **in an update panel** which calls a js method to do printing of the current window:

```
<a href="javascript:print()" id="cpMain_popupCouponDescriptionControl_hrefPrint">Print Coupon</a>
```

where the js method is called on Page_Load event:

```
private void loadJs()
{
    String flashMap = "script";
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.Page.GetType(), flashMap))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), flashMap, "function print(){ alert('test'); window.print(); return false; }", true);
    }
}
```

When pressing the link, the alert window is shown multiple times (after I click "Ok", which seems strange) but window.print() is never called (a new tab for printing is not opened).

If I directly call `javascript:window.link` from `href` it works, but because the link is contained in an update panel, it no longer works second time (that's why I tried to register the script).

Can anybody see the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `window.print();` is actually calling your `print()` function recursively. Try changing the name of your js function.